# Are there benefits to running X86-64 Python on a 64-bit CPU in a 64-bit OS?

Tags: python, windows-7, 64-bit, x86-64

What kind of benefits are there to running the amd64 builds of Python and extensions?  (Lots of extensions [compiled for amd64 here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).)  I have an i5 processor and Win7 64-bit, so it seems like it would be appropriate.  But it also sounds like it is buggy, beta, unsupported, etc.

Does it actually provide a performance benefit?  In which areas?  I'd be running SciPy, NumPy, etc.  I occasionally get "out of memory" errors with 32-bit Python and my machine has 4 GiB of RAM.

Can win32 packages be installed on a 64-bit Python base if no 64-bit version of the package exists?

Comment: The difficulty of installing this is now obsolete thanks to Anaconda, etc.  Maybe question should be rephrased to just cover benefits of 64-bit Python?

Comment: If you would do that all past answers become obsolete. Its better to ask a new question and refer to this question. Some requirements for asking and content criteria have changed over time so reference to this question is definitely a must have!

Comment: If you would ask such new question include some benchmark testing images for 32bit vs. 64bit software versions. I.m.h.o. the test needs to include an equal amount of floating-point as well as integer calculations, GPU vs. CPU and combined CPU/GPU work, various specific cos, tan, sin calculation operations to make its scientifically relevant as well. And last but not least some pygames for the sake of fun... Snake Tetris, and Pacman!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The primary rationale to use a 64-bit Python is that you can access more than 2GB of main memory, e.g. if you have large dicts, lists, or long strings. This requires that you actually have that much memory in your system to be practical.

A secondary effect is that in AMD64 mode, the CPU has more registers, so the resulting code may run slightly faster (for integer operations).

Python in 64-bit mode on Windows certainly is not beta or unsupported. It may be buggy, but only if you actually do have very large data structures. 64-bit Python has been around 15 years (though not on Windows).

Comment: Wouldn't more registers speed up anything that uses registers, not just integer operations?

Comment: @endolith: since the additional registers are integer registers, code that uses floating point operations extensively can't benefit from that widening. Of course, you rarely have code that purely uses floating point operations, so indeed any code may benefit - unless it did already deal fine with the x86 registers alone.

Comment: @endolith and Martin: x86-64 has twice as many XMM registers (16) as well as having 16 integer registers.  Even better, the ABI specifies passing / returning FP args in XMM registers instead of in legacy x87 registers.  Having SSE2 as a required part of the architecture is very nice, and means that all programs can use it without checking CPUID feature bits.

Comment: The main benefit of x86-64 for a lot of cases is that it's typically ~10% faster than the same code compiled for 32bit.  Of course it's great if you have a use for large amounts of memory, or 64bit integers.  (Or arbitrary-precision integers like Python uses)

Answer (score 7):

Same advantage as every other 64-bit program: lots of process space, and access to more and larger registers (for the VM and C modules at least). But no, you need to find 64-bit versions of the C modules.

Answer (score 6):

The normal gains one get by using 64bit code in general. I haven't found any recent benchmarks, but at the time of x64 introduction, code could run up to 30% faster on 64bit than on 32bit on x86 hardware -- this gap certainly has fallen somehow with the optimizatgions since the time, but is still probably faster.

Also, you benefit of being ablle to transparantly use more than 4GB of memory should you need too.

Note however that the speed gains in 64bit are due to the awfull 32bit legacy ABI: enve a core i7 running in 32 bit has the same 4 general purpose registers (and a couple others) one had in the 80386 chip from 1987. And those mapped 1:1 to the register on the 8086 from the 70's. The 64 bit abi introduces more (real) general purpose registers, and that makes it for the speed gain. Otherwise, 64 bit code simply spends double the cache memory, which makes it, in other architectures, like PPC, be actually slower than 32bit code.

Answer (score 5):

I've been running 64-bit Python on Linux for years already. No problems, it's not buggy. That includes numpy. I wouldn't worry about that.

One small benefit:

```
Python> sys.maxint
9223372036854775807
```

However, I suppose one could argue if there is any benefit to that, but the same goes for all 64-bit apps in general.

You get the most benefit when dealing with very large amounts of data.

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine you'd get performance increases with SciPy and NumPy since number handling and calculations is what gets vastly improved when you add more bits to a processor. But I can't be sure.

You could always run 64 bit and 32 bit side by side and do some comparisons, I'd be interested to know the results of tests on the number crunching side. And if you're running the same version of both, the code will run on both fine provided you have the modules you need for both.

Comment: I did a very minimal comparison timeit fft(rand(1021)). Using Python(x,y) 32-bit: 3.37 ms per loop.  Using 64-bit MKL version: 2.56 ms per loop