# Unhandled exit code when loading Nifti with SimpleITK in python

Tags: python-2.7, itk

I am trying to load .nii.gz files using SimpleITK in python using PyCharm. Ideally, ITK has a [NIFTI class](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1NiftiImageIO.html) and I followed these [tutorials](https://github.com/curiale/Medical-Image-Analysis-IPython-Tutorials/blob/master/tutorial_1/tutorial_1_basics.ipynb), so I presume SimpleITK has a wrapper for NIFTI class in ITK. The issue is I get a weird exit code which has no documentation (as per google) like this

**Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)**

The code is as simple as it gets :

```
import numpy as np
import SimpleITK as sitk

image = sitk.ReadImage(filename)
imageSize = image.GetSize()
```

I also tried using nibabel library to load the same image format but I always get a MemoryError, even though, TaskManager (not the best approach) says I have sufficient memory.

The file is ~123 Mb. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you share your file? What other applications are you able to open your file with? Please try slicer3D or ITKsnap.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to research purposes I can't share the file. I can open it with slicer3D and ITKsnap but I want to load it with python for automatic segmentation. It is around ~123 Mb as I said. I also want to point out that I am using python 32 bit on a 64 bit machine. This is because I couldn't load sitk in 64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to anyone who might land onto this problem, it was an issue with the version of python. I was using 32 bit Python on a 64 bit Windows PC, when I changed it to 64 bit Python and installed the wheels files [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib), the strange exit code was gone. I would also recommend following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117626/should-i-use-python-32bit-or-python-64bit).

Comment: What python wheel were you using before which caused the problem?

Comment: I was using python wheels from the 32 bit from the same website as mentioned in the answer. Now I use everything in 64 bit

Comment: Did you try the official wheels on PyPi? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SimpleITK/0.9.1 (32-bit) https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SimpleITK/0.10.0 (64-bit only)

Comment: I did, a while back but then I was also trying to get to work with anaconda. I don't understand how this is relevant.

Comment: The source of the problem may be incorrectly compiled binaries SimpleITK wheels (from lfd.uci.edu), or that the binary wheels are incompatible with your Python distribution.

Comment: That is, in this case, the issue.