# Nonzero exit code on ITK filter

Tags: python, numpy, itk

I am using an ITK [BinaryThinningImageFilter3D](https://www.custusx.org/uploads/developer_doc/nightly/classitk_1_1_binary_thinning_image_filter3_d.html). However, the code (where `mask` is an `np.uint8` 3D Numpy array filled with `0`s and `1`s - it is a voxel representation of an arthery)

```
import itk
output = itk.BinaryThinningImageFilter3D.New(
    itk.GetImageFromArray(mask)
)
```

gives

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39977289/1185254) points towards Python version - I checked it, everything is x64. I am leaning towards some kind of data type incompatibility. Any hints on how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out [there was a segfault](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITKThickness3D/issues/16). Issue fixed in new version of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap this in a `try...catch` block and print the error message. That will tell you what went wrong. Perhaps something like:

```
try:
  import itk
  output = itk.BinaryThinningImageFilter3D.New(
    itk.GetImageFromArray(mask))
except RuntimeError as e:
  print('Got an exception\n' + str(e))
```

Comment: But that's the point - ITK terminates the program. It never reaches `except` clause.

Comment: How about `except itk.ExceptionObject as e:`?

Comment: This doesn't work either. Program simply terminates while in the C code part.