# 64-bit Python not working in 64-bit computer, whereas 32-bit Python works

Tags: python, 32bit-64bit

I have a 64-bits Windows 7 computer, with several 64-bits programs installed and working perfectly. However, when I try to execute Python 3.5 or Python 3.6 for 64-bits I receive the following error "The application could not be properly initialize. We must quit."

I have installed Python 3.5 for 32-bits and it works. The problem is that I'm trying to install Cantera, which requires to have the same architecture for Matlab (64-bits) and Python, so I need 64-bit Python.

Could you please provide information about how to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You should provide more precise description of the problem, because now it is way too broad.

Comment: OK. 32-bits Python works in my 64-bit computer, but I need the 64-bit version. However, the 64-version "cannot be properly initialized". How can I fix this problem?

Comment: if you sure your computer is `64bit`, check `BIOS` settings(CPU settings(Architecture)). Maybe is an `Kernel` issue .

Comment: My BIOS version is American Megatrends 5.03., date 05-dec-2008. Sorry, I am not an expert in informatics... what should I check about this BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

64 bit version will allow a single process to use more RAM than 32 bit, however you may find that the memory footprint doubles depending on what you are storing in RAM (Integers in particular).

For example if your app requires > 2GB of RAM, so you switch from 32bit to 64bit you may find that your app is now requiring > 4GB of RAM.

Check whether all of your 3rd party modules are available in 64 bit, otherwise it may be easier to stick to 32bit in the meantime

[See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117626/should-i-use-python-32bit-or-python-64bit)

Comment: Third party modules are not the official modules but just an extension or python wrapper. See https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: OK, but I am not deciding whether to install 32-bit or 64-bit. I want to install the 64-bit version, but the problem is that it doesn't work, despite my computer is 64-bits.

Answer (score 0):

Might it be that you have two python versions installed and the old 32 bit version is sitting in your $PATH? If the new version is not in $PATH, your script requiring this new version will not see it out of the box. If you didn't specify the new python version when initializing your script (which requires the new python version), it finds only the old version and misbehaves. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I don't think so. I installed first the 64-bit version, when I dind't have any other versions in my computer. That version was in the $PATH, but it didn't work.

Comment: Also, I'm not trying to execute any script by the moment, I am just trying to open the terminal through Start->All programs->Python 32-bit or Python 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already reinstalled python and confirmed your installation file has the correct md5 fingerprint:

1. Click on the Start and choose Run.
2. Type eventvwr
3. Now launch any software (python console?), reproduce error.
4. Click on Start, then navigate to Settings, Control Panel. Find Event Viewer in the Administrative tools.
5. Let us know what you find there.

Comment: Something as: "Emerging application: python.exe - Application error: The application could not be properly initialized (0xc000007b)"